# My code could not recognize special characters

Tags: java, selenium

I have a test where it would verify to see if the username will display where the login and log out is. Here is the object html.

`<span class="MuiButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 3c1.66 0 3 1.34 3 3s-1.34 3-3 3-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3zm0 14.2c-2.5 0-4.71-1.28-6-3.22.03-1.99 4-3.08 6-3.08 1.99 0 5.97 1.09 6 3.08-1.29 1.94-3.5 3.22-6 3.22z"></path></svg>&nbsp;&nbsp;CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼</span>`

I copied the element

`<span class="MuiButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 3c1.66 0 3 1.34 3 3s-1.34 3-3 3-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3zm0 14.2c-2.5 0-4.71-1.28-6-3.22.03-1.99 4-3.08 6-3.08 1.99 0 5.97 1.09 6 3.08-1.29 1.94-3.5 3.22-6 3.22z"></path></svg>&nbsp;&nbsp;CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼</span>`

Here is my code , and it kept on printing Fail which make me believe that it could not match the text. I also noticed that when it print out the values instead of the ▼ it printed out as `CLARA ADAMS (autotest)`?

How can I modify my code so that I could recognize `CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼`?

```
    // Get the Text from the location 
    if (driver.findElement(By.className("MuiButton-label"))
            .getText().equalsIgnoreCase("CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼")) {
        System.out.println("CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼ Pass");
    } else {
        System.out.println("CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼ Fail");

    }
```

Comment: Is the text supposed to be `"   CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼ "`, or `"CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼"`?  Note that one has spaces before and after, and the other doesn't.

Comment: no spaces before and after. And this is the run result CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ? Fail. I notice, the testng returned ? instead of the triangle. So i tried to change the triangle to ? but still get a fail.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your program? Could you checkif something related to Java Unicode / UTF-8 / UTF-16

Comment: i am running it through eclipse testNG

Answer (score 0):

Takeout if else and use assert:

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.className("MuiButton-label"));
```

`assertEquals(username.getText().trim(), "CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼");`

This is same as if else.

So if your assert fails you will get error that expected was this and actual is this so what you can do is copy from actual and paste it into assert, If selenium throws error for special character "▼" as long as the name is correct.

Comment: so i figured it out. I used this to find out the text in the field WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.className("MuiButton-label")); System.out.println(webElement.getText()); and then i realized there are actually 2 spaces in front of CLARA. After i put those two spaces in it works like a charm.

Comment: still you can use assert as if else increases the length of code whereas assert is just one line code.

Comment: There are two whitespaces in front of CLARA. i want to trim out the whitespaces out. I wonder what would be the best way to do it.

Comment: `String name = driver.findElement(By.className("MuiButton-label"))  .getText().trim()
    .split("\\s")[0];`   \\s will split the spaces

Comment: how can i implement this trim with the existing code?

Comment: [link] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm) I have updated the answer just `.trim()` in assert. It will remove blank space from both the sides. As there is blank space before "Clara" so you will get text like "CLARA ADAMS (autotest) ▼"